# Connecting two computers through Ethernet wire and data transfer

Tags: windows, ethernet, batch-file, file-sharing

I know how to share files and transfer data through Ethernet by assigning IP and getting through by giving the right credentials.

Is there a way to do this more simpler or any other way without assigning IP to to a particular value to the other system ?
Like a set of commands in command prompt to be written as a bat file?

Comment: use the homegroup feature which is part since Windows 7:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IP address is very necessary for 2 devices to communicate, even if you create a batch file to transfer the files you have to use a protocols like FTP / Telnet / SSH / HTTP GET and PUT but without IP how the protocols in batch file will talk to the other device or how will it know I have transferred the file to right machine?

Or if you don't want to use IP address at all, then you will have to relay on non-Ethernet communication like copy the file to pendrive and then transfer.

Thanks,

Manjesh

Comment: Let's put IP apart. My main aim is concerned about transferring data by using a batch file. If I have to set the IP for once , its not a matter. How do I write a batch file for that? Or is there any other way other than batch file or home group by using Ethernet only.

Comment: @AravindS, please tell me what exactly are you looking for? are we trying to get a batch file which will copy files from one machine to another or with in the same machine?

Comment: @AravindS, you can take a look at this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_transfer

Comment: I want a batch file that can transfer data from one machine to another . only thing I have to tell is the location of the file to it everytime I use it.

Comment: So just to understand you have 2 computers connected directly with static IP address and need to have a batch file on source machine.

When ever you execute the batch file that should ask you for the file location and automatically push it to the destination machine right?

Comment: Yes. A batch file that pushes my data to the other system. I just give that file location in the host computer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33845/discussion-between-manjesh23-and-aravind-s).